# Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero in R (KlaR package)

Tags: r, null, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with 188 columns and 100 rows (plus a header row). I'm trying to apply the `kmodes` clustering method (from `klaR` package) in R to this matrix.

There are two types of data in the array data structure: string and binary. Both have null values.

For example:

```
 Q27_history     Q28
      1          <NA> 
    <NA>    yes, sometimes
```

function to compute total within-cluster sum of square:

```
set.seed (96743)

# function to compute total within-cluster sum of square 
wss <- function(k) {
  sum((kmodes( whois_data, k)$withindiff))
}

# Compute and plot wss for k = 1 to k = 15
k.values <- 2:15

# extract wss for 2-15 clusters
wss_values <- map_dbl(k.values, wss)

print(wss_values)
```

The text of error:

```
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

Afret that:

```
Error in print(wss_values) :object 'wss_values' is not found
```

I've tried to put `kmodes(na.fill(data, fill=""), k)` in:

```
wss <- function(k) {
  sum((kmodes( whois_data, k)$withindiff))
  kmodes(na.fill(data, fill=""), k)
}
```

But after that `library(purrr)` stop working and does not find variable `map_dbl`

How should I inline rows with empty data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have NAs when using kmodes, it should throw an error:

```
set.seed(111)
whois_data = data.frame(Q1 = rbinom(100,1,0.5),
Q2 = sample(c("Y","N"),100,replace=TRUE),
Q3 = sample(c(NA,1:3),100,replace=TRUE))

kmodes(whois_data,3)

Error in old.cluster != cluster : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
```

Makes more sense to do kmodes without the NAs :

```
wss <- function(k,df) {
  sum((kmodes(df, k)$withindiff))
}

library(purrr)

map_dbl(2:5, wss,df = whois_data[complete.cases(whois_data),])
[1] 91 58 70 42
```